# Função para inverter strings em C

Tags: c

Insere a string orig no início da string dest, retornando dest.

char *strins(char *dest, char *orig)

Meu código ficou o seguinte:

```
char *strins(char *dest, char *orig)
{
    return strcat(*orig,*dest);
}

main()
{
    char s[] = "World";
    strins(s, "Hello");
    printf(s);
}
```

A função deve funcionar assim:

```
char s[100] = "Autonoma";
strins(s, "Universidade");
printf(s);  ->  UniversidadeAutonoma
```

Comment: Não é inversão de strings. Inversão de strings é transformar `"roma"` em `"amor"`. O que você quer é concatenar strings e retornar em um ponto específico

Comment: Aproveitando, qual o problema no seu código? O que está acontecendo?

Comment: `char s[] = "World"`, qual será o tamanho de `s`? Terá espaço para você adicionar outro texto nela? A função `strcat` espera como parâmetro dois ponteiros para `char`. A ordem dos argumentos de `strcat` é `destination` e `source`, por que passou `orig` e `dest` nesta ordem?

Comment: O código não exibe a string mesmo que seja s[20], por exemplo.

Comment: A intenção é que o argumento dest fique na frente

Comment: Então qual a saída?

Comment: Só retorna um valor: "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem diversos problemas em seu código.

Primeiramente, quando você define uma string literal com `char s[] = "World";` você está alocando apenas o espaço na memória necessário para aquele número específico de caracteres.

Como você quer juntar duas strings, o tamanho vai aumentar, precisando então de mais espaço. Isso se resolve por exemplo definindo um tamanho máximo com  `char s[100] = "World";`.

Além disso você não pode modificar um string literal, então você não pode fazer a função da forma que você fez e esperar que funcione com `strins(s, "Hello");`
visto que ele não vai conseguir modificar a string literal `"Hello"`.

Por último, o resultado da função `strcat` é salvo no primeiro parâmetro, então estaria sendo salvo no `orig` ao invés de `dest` como desejado. Um `strcpy` vai bastar, embora **vá deixar a variável de origem "suja"**, o que não sei se é um problema.

Segue o código com os problemas sugeridos corrigidos:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *strins(char *dest, char *orig)
{

    strcat(orig,dest);
    strcpy(dest,orig);
    return dest;
}

int main()
{
    char s[100] = "World";
    char outro[100]= "Hello";
    strins(s,outro);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Que retorna o resultado:

```
HelloWorld
```

Comment: Se não me engano, você está, também, alterando o valor de `orig`. Não que esteja na descrição do problema não alterar `orig`, mas seria adequado não alterá-la. Assim, seu código não vale para a chamada `string(s, "Universidade");`, que é o exemplo base

Comment: Eu acredito ter já deixado claro na resposta o que você citou quando escrevi: ```embora vá deixar a varíavel de origem "suja", o que não sei se é um problema.```. Além disso, no final, o printf feito é exatamente o proposto pelo exemplo base, e retorna o pedido. Vou editar a resposta para adicionar o resultado encontrado.

Comment: Na minha leitura eu passei por cima desse trecho.

Comment: Ok! Sem problemas. É sempre bom tentar deixar as respostas o mais claro possível.